# Inscribing a triangle in a triangle

Tags: geometry

Say we have two triangles $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta DEF$ with already determined angle sizes. Does there exist a triangle $\Delta XYZ$ similar to $\Delta DEF$ such that $\Delta XYZ$ can be inscribed in $\Delta ABC$?

Intuitively the answer seems to be yes but I can't prove this rigorously. Should I be attempting to use an argument with degrees of freedom or is that the wrong idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice "duality" trick. Instead of trying to inscribe a triangle similar to $DEF$ inside $ABC$, it is easier to circumscribe a triangle similar to $ABC$ around $DEF$:

[image]

It is enough to draw the parallel to $BC$ through $D$, the parallel to $AB$ through $E$ and the parallel to $AC$ through $F$.